# How manieth element is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I know the how manieth an element is? (using Javascript or jQuery)
Suppose I have one UL with multiple LI within, how do I know wheter the LI clicked is the 4th or the 6th?

```
$('li').click(function(){
    nth = $(this).nth();
    alert(nth);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this.

```
​$("li").click(function() {
    var nth = $("ul li").index($(this));
    alert(nth);
});​
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvzLC/)

Comment: The advantage of this answer above the answers using $(this).index() is that it also works correctly if some of the children of the ul element are not li elements.

Comment: @Confusion - If the ul had direct children that weren't li elements, would they be valid elements? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul I guess that doesn't change the fact that some browsers would consider them in the index anyway.

Comment: @KevinB - I thought you were allowed to nest lists directly, but it seems that has been deprecated, as discussed in e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try a `nth = $(this).prevAll().count() + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the index method:

```
var nth = $(this).index()+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like

```
$('li').each(function (i) {
  $(this).data("pos", i);
}).click(function() {
  var nth = $(this).data("pos");
  alert(nth);
});
```

Invariably, I end up needing the position for other things, so I save it off.