# HTML nested ordered list

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

I'd like to produce the following in HTML:

```
1. One
2. Two
  1. Inner One
  2. Inner Two
3. Three
```

One way is

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Inner One</li>
    <li>inner Two</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

But according to [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) this is not the proper way to do this. The "proper" way produces this:

```
1. One
2. Two
3.
  1. Inner One
  2. Inner Two
4. Three
```

So, is there a proper way to nest ordered lists without extra numbers appearing for the nested lists?

Comment: Why do you think the `3.` is in there? It's nesting, not another `li`.

Comment: For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/xuh6z/1 Note, you want `ol`, not `ul` too.

Comment: Did you actually try reading the answers to [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

Comment: Both examples in [Proper way to make HTML nested list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) actually give the desired output, but with a little correction: `<ul>` to `<ol>`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<ol> 
  <li>One</li> 
  <li>Two
    <ol> 
      <li>Inner One</li> 
      <li>inner Two</li> 
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li> 
</ol>
```

gives

1. One
2. Two

   1. Inner One
   2. inner Two
3. Three

`<ul>` is for *u*nordered lists.

Comment: Sorry meant to use ol. Thanks for pointing this out and the response!

Answer (score 4):

I think, you are searching for this:

```
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two
  <ol>
    <li>Inner One</li>
    <li>inner Two</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

Outputs to:

```
1. One
2. Two
   1. Inner One
   2. Inner Two
3. Three
```

Answer (score -3):

As stated above you just need an ordered list

```
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <ol>
      <li>inner 1</li> 
      <li>inner 2</li>
  </ol>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: No, this is what you _shouldn't_ do