# How to move Html sub elements out of main elements?

Tags: c#, html

In my html editor, when i using Html editor ( Kendo Editor) to generate bullet, then i indent it to create sub-bullet, the **html** return is not in my expect.

```
<ul>
    <li>Focusing on lifetime income replacement
        <ul><li>Investing in continuous service and innovation</li></ul>
    </li>

    <li>Advocating for an improved retirement system</li>
    <li>Achieving total financial wellness</li>
    <li>Providing a distinctive, multichannel user experience for participants and plan sponsors </li>
</ul>
```

As you see, the ul tag is inside the li tag and it affect my report ( i use itextsharp to create pdf ).

How can c# move the ul tag outside li ? can anyone give me a solution.
My expect is :

```
<ul>
    <li>Focusing on lifetime income replacement

    </li>
    <ul> // Move to here
        <li>Investing in continuous service and innovation</li> 
    </ul>
    <li>Advocating for an improved retirement system</li>
    <li>Achieving total financial wellness</li>
    <li>Providing a distinctive, multichannel user experience for participants and plan sponsors </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

The way the HTML is generated in your first example is correct.

When nesting lists, each sublist should be inside an li element.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list).

Comment: Hi tarnold86, in my case, i have to convert to this format, iTextsharp generate blank with first format .... Thank you