# only show those div where i do mouse-over

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to show icon on those word where i hover.

[Here is the fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a5gYA/)
, currently if i mouse over on child `<li>` then parent `<ul>` icon is also showing...

### What  i want is:

If i mouse-over on any row then only 1 & corresponding   icon should show, it should not show parent icon.

Please see the [fiddle to know more](http://fiddle.jshell.net/a5gYA/).

Please help! Is it possible to solve with Jquery?

**It looks like:**

[image]

**I used this css**

```
 #project-div-id ul li { list-style: circle ; margin-top: 2px; width: 175px; }
 #project-div-id ul li img {list-style: circle ;  display: none; }
 #project-div-id ul li:hover img { display: inline; float: right; } 
 .add_btn,.del_btn,.edit_btn{
 padding-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: Your fiddle has a miss-matched <li> tag.  Other than that, the css should work.

Comment: Oh -- i see, it's nested.  Fiddling atm...

Comment: anyway there is no way to select the parent with css only

Comment: @circusdei http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140414-irjs-39kb.jpg

Comment: Not sure why it's been downvoted...

Comment: @HaSuKrOnOs  & then how to solve it with jquery ?

Comment: Is this the intended result? http://fiddle.jshell.net/n2HbY/

Comment: @circusdei Yes, but only it is working fine with fiddle, when i copied your css to my application, it is again showing same issue >> http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140414-2xfj-10kb.jpg

Comment: The changes were in the html. checkout ul/li nesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: CAN ANYONE TELL ME , WHY -VOTE? PLEASE WRITE COMMENT, SO THAT  I CAN IMPROVE MY QUESTION...

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are nesting the <ul>'s and not just using one single <ul> + <li>'s - is there a reason for that?

Comment: @SaminOz i have update a php code above, please see, it like tree structure, user can add project on each project until infinite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the `>`, `li > img` selects only direct children that are img's:

```
ul img{
    display: none;
}
li:hover >img{
    display: inlineblock
}
<ul>
    <li>text 1 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img1" /></li>
    <li>text 2 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img2" /></li>
    <li>text 3 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img3" /></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li> 4 1 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img41" />
            <li> 4 2 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img42" />
            <li> 4 3 <img src="img.jpg" alt="img43" />                
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example, on hover on li 4->li 1:
`li:hover img` selects all img's anywhere in this li (or it's children, etc)
`li:hover > img` selects all img's that are direct descendants , not the ones deeper, like a new ul/li.

Comment: Please see my update php code, how i can i improve that in order get my work done!

Comment: This is all about css, not php. This is not a site where you get custom made solved problems, we give you the problem in a way iy can fix it