# Markers is a nested list

Tags: html, css

I want to find out whether it is possible to make out the markers to create a counter.

Just what I was able to achieve can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeen/w6V74/1/

```
ol { 
  counter-reset: level-1; 
  list-style: none; 
  padding-left: 0;
} 
ol li:before { 
  counter-increment: level-1; 
  content: counter(level-1) '. ';
} 


ol ol { 
  counter-reset: level-2; 
  padding-left: 15px;
}
ol ol li:before { 
  counter-increment: level-2; 
  content: counter(level-1) '.' counter(level-2) '. ';
}


ol ol ol { 
  counter-reset: level-3; 
  padding-left: 30px;
} 
ol ol ol li:before { 
  counter-increment: level-3; 
  content: counter(level-1) '.' counter(level-2) '.' counter(level-3) '. '; 
}
```

[image]

In the end, I want to get what is shown in the second image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check this page and change the way to nest your `<ol>`:
[Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

After you properly nest the list, add css below:

```
ol {
    display: table;
}
ol > li {
    display: table-row;
}
ol > li::before {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/naokiota/95xha/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of styling the indentations.

Modify your CSS by adding the following rules:

```
ol > li {
    padding-left: 1.0em;
    position: relative;
}
ol > ol > li {
    padding-left: 2.0em;
    position: relative;
}
ol > ol > ol > li {
    padding-left: 3.0em;
    position: relative;
}
ol li:before { 
    counter-increment: level-1; 
    content: counter(level-1) '. ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Take the generated content (`ol li:before`) out of the regular flow by using `position: absolute`.

The trick is to add some padding to the left with a suitable length to accommodate the counter label.

For each list item (`ol>li`, `ol>ol>li`, `ol>ol>ol>li`), set the `padding-left` to `1.0em`, `2.0em`, `3.0em` respectively (or some similar values) and use `position: relative` to allow the generated content elements to be positioned with respect to the appropriate `li` parent element.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/m2vZd/

Comment: @JeenJay Either way is good, CSS table-cells are a good option and a bit easier to implement in this situation.