# List element inside list element doesn't work CSS

Tags: html, css, list

```
<ul>
     <li>This
          <li>and this</li>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I try to select the second `<li>` by doing:

```
li li {
    background: "red";
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: you should wrap it in another `ul`. the browsers are implicitly closing the first list item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one ul... And the document is not valid HTML5. Try this one (this is a proper way of nesting lists):

```
<ul>
     <li>This
         <ul>
             <li>and this</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Then in CSS:

```
ul li ul li {
    background: "red";
}
```

More to read here: [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

Best regards, hope it helps!