# CSS Menu Disappears after Hover

Tags: html, css

I am learning css and I have created a vertical menu, hovering the mouse over the first menu item shows the sub-menu across.  But my problem is, as soon as I move the mouse to the sub-menu, it disappears.  How can I make it so it stays there until I clicked one of the sub-menu items?  Please help.

Already searched through a lot of examples but none similar to this.  I'm new to css and I'm not sure if my approach is the correct for this menu setup requirement.  Please enlighten.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

.navLeft {
 width: 25%;
 margin-top: 0%;
 top: auto;
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 5%;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
 /* [disabled]clear: none; */
}

.navLeft ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 6em;
 height: 2em;
 /* [disabled]list-style-position: inside; */
 color: #F14E23;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 0.5em solid #000000;
 margin-bottom: -0.5em;
 font-family: alfa-slab-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding-top: 2em;
 top: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
 transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -0.5em;
}

.navLeft ul li:hover {
 background-color: #F14E23;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
}
.navLeft ul .about {
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: all .1s linear 0s;
 -o-transition: all .1s linear 0s;
 transition: all .1s linear 0s;
}
.navLeft ul ul li
 {
 float: left;
}
.navLeft ul .projects {
 clear: left;
}

.navLeft ul ul {
 display: none;
}

.navLeft ul .about:hover ~ ul{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>STORY</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<section class="mainMid">
<nav class="navLeft">
    <ul>
      <li class="about">ABOUT</li>
      <ul>
          <li class="navBeginning">BEGINNING</li>
          <li class="navMnv">Mission<br>
                  <br>
                  Vision</li>
          <li class="navPeople">People</li>
      </ul>
      <li class="projects">PROJECTS</li>
      <li class="getinvolved">GET<br>
          INVOLVED</li>
      <li class="records">RECORDS</li>
      <li class="donate">DONATE</li>
    </ul>
      
      
  </nav>

</section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @KingShimkus what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zt8ffu11/

html:

```
<section class="mainMid">
<nav class="navLeft">
    <ul>
      <li class="about">ABOUT
      <ul>
          <li class="navBeginning">BEGINNING</li>
          <li class="navMnv">Mission<br>
                  <br>
                  Vision</li>
          <li class="navPeople">People</li>
      </ul>
        </li>      
      <li class="projects">PROJECTS</li>
      <li class="getinvolved">GET<br>
          INVOLVED</li>
      <li class="records">RECORDS</li>
      <li class="donate">DONATE</li>
    </ul>


  </nav>

</section>
```

css:
    .navLeft {
        width: 25%;
        margin-top: 0%;
        top: auto;
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 5%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        /* [disabled]clear: none; */
    }

```
.navLeft ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 6em;
    height: 2em;
    /* [disabled]list-style-position: inside; */
    color: #F14E23;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0.5em solid #000000;
    margin-bottom: -0.5em;
    font-family: alfa-slab-one;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 2em;
    top: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
}

.navLeft ul li:hover {
    background-color: #F14E23;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.navLeft ul .about {
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .1s linear 0s;
    transition: all .1s linear 0s;
}
.navLeft ul ul li
 {
    float: left;
}
.navLeft ul .projects {
    clear: left;
}

.navLeft ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.navLeft ul .about:hover  ul{
    display: block;
}
```

and for list structure check is question [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the sub-menu goes back to vertical.

Comment: Just read your link regarding the nested list. I didn't even realize it. Thanks for the info.