# Multiple UL inside LI?

Tags: html

Im creating a nested grid based menu. UL = row and LI = column. The outcome is successful and I was able to avoid too much div mark ups.

My question is if it's VALID to have multiple instances of UL inside LI?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">(VALID)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">(VALID)</a>
            <ul>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">(I'M NOT SURE)</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                    </ul>  
                    <ul>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                        <li>any contents here</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5hwr2e4/1/)

Comment: `if it's VALID to have multiple instances of UL inside LI?`

Yes

Comment: `<ul><li>  <ul><li></li></ul> </li></ul>`

You can nest it to as many levels as u want

Comment: Where is the Fiddle link?

Comment: Im still tring to edit the description, the links is nto appearing, I'm newbie here :). http://jsfiddle.net/h5hwr2e4/

Comment: It's valid; I'm not so sure it's elegant.

Comment: You had some missing tags and I have corrected it
http://jsfiddle.net/h5hwr2e4/1/

Comment: Have you followed the instructions given by the error message on how to format your markup correctly?

Comment: Try visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: Thanks guys. @colour, my example is there are multi ULs inside a LI and were not nested properly. If we can add anything inside LI, maybe the question now is if it's elegant or not :)

Comment: Yes as long you are not forget `</li>`. Multiple `<p> ... </p>`, `<h1> ... </h1>`, `<table> ... </table>`, `<ul> ... </ul>`, `<ol> ... </ol>` and many available tags can defined inside `<li> ... </li>`

Answer (score 4):

Yes ......its vaild.....
You can nest it to as much  as u want ..there is no limit.  .....