# Position child element at baseline and flush right within list (`<li>`) item

Tags: html, css, position

I want the price of coffee to come at the right end of the coffee name i.e 1.80 price should come in line of Americano. Similarly 10.00 price should come in line of Macchiato.

[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul#container {
  width: 18%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 15px solid #886633;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#container li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
}
#container > li {
  font-size: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
em {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li>DRINK MENU
  <ul>
    <li><span>Latte</span><em>2.79</em>
    </li>
    <li><span>Cappucino</span><em>2.99</em>
    </li>
    <li><span>Cafe Americano</span><em>1.80</em>
    </li>
    <li><span>Espresso</span><em>2.00</em>
    </li>
    <li><span>Carmel Macchiato</span><em>10.00</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see i am using relative position, but its not working.
Can you solve this without absolute position and minimum changes to the code?
**Just tell me why is relative position not working.**

Comment: Any reason for not using `position: absolute`?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Your inner `ul` is nested impropertly. Your code renders fine in Chrome, but messed up in jsfiddle. Consider cleaning that up first.

Comment: @leo.fcx absolute position removes the element from the flow, i am making a responsive web design. It needs to adjust according to window size.

Comment: @VarunJ, your prices would be absolutely positioned within the `<li>` container, not the viewport. It will be as responsive as the container. Test it.

Comment: @Michael_B it works fine in jsfiddle. Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjpnfos/1/)

Comment: proper way to nest an unordered list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: your exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/dkohs6m5/

Comment: @Michael_B it works fine in safari, chrome and firefox. What else i want?

Comment: If your question has been answered by somebody, then give it a checkmark and an upvote. If not, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Outside of the code, note that "Cappuccino" is spelled incorrectly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to fix your html - the closing `li` for the DRINK MENU should be after the nested `ul`.

Then I would make use of `display:table` css:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul#container {
  width: 18%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 15px solid #886633;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#container > li {
  padding: 5px;
}
#container ul {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#container ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#container span,
#container em {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
#container em {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <li>DRINK MENU
    <ul>
      <li><span>Latte</span><em>2.79</em>
      </li>
      <li><span>Cappucino</span><em>2.99</em>
      </li>
      <li><span>Cafe Americano</span><em>1.80</em>
      </li>
      <li><span>Espresso</span><em>2.00</em>
      </li>
      <li><span>Carmel Macchiato</span><em>10.00</em>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comments about overflow.  There are a couple of ways to fix this:

1. Increase the min width of `ul#container` to something that will accommodate the longest line - in this case a width of 125px should suffice: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/470nahy4/3/)
2. Add `table-layout:fixed` to your table `li`  and add `word-wrap:break-word` to the `span`: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/470nahy4/2/)

Comment: Your answer does not solve in jsfiddle. The price is overflowing and its not in line with the coffee name. I purposely gave less space to coffee name, so that it takes two lines. BTW you were right about my <li> not closing in right place.

Comment: See edited answer,  I have also changed it so the prices are aligned to the bottom

Comment: You did a miracle with three line of code. I am choosing this a correct answer. If you know why did relative position didn't work then do answer.

Comment: I think with the relative positioning, when the container gets too small, it will always "push" one of either the span or em onto the next line - in this case as you have floated the em, the span gets pushed down.  Again the overflowing will be because of the width being too small and you wouldn't be able to vertical align the price to the bottom as you would want

Comment: You used 'table' and 'table-cell'. Why didn't you use 'table-row'. Is it not necessary, can it be omitted.

Comment: Yeah, not really needed unless you are wanting multiple rows.  I guess to be absolutely semantic, you could make the `ul` table, the `li` table-row and the `span`s and `em`s table-cell

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the `<em>`

**HTML**

```
<ul id="container">
<li>DRINK MENU</li>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Latte</span><em>2.79</em></li>
        <li><span>Cappucino</span><em>2.99</em></li>
        <li><span>Cafe Americano</span><em class="bottom">1.80</em></li>
        <li><span>Espresso</span><em>2.00</em></li>
        <li><span>Carmel Macchiato</span><em class="bottom">10.00</em></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{ 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    }
ul#container{
    width: 18%;
    min-width: 200px ;
    max-width: 400px;
    border: 15px solid #886633;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: orange ;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
#container  li{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
    }
#container > li{
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
em{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    }
.bottom {
    position: relative;
    top:15px;
}
span{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block ;
    }
```

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjpnfos/)

Another posible solution (maybe the best practice):

**CSS:**

```
li:nth-child(3) > em, li:nth-child(5) > em{
    position: relative;
    top:16px;
}
```

[**<kbd>DEMO</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kjpnfos/1/)

Comment: This will solve the current situation but what about future entries, and what if the coffee name goes to the third line. I wonder why does relative position does not work.

Comment: I added another solution, using `:nth-child`

Comment: this n-th child is even more specific, what if the menu changes and price in question is not in same row anymore. I am looking for something "bulletproof"

Comment: I only answered and find a solution to your current problem. The answer of @Pete maybe is appropriate in your "future" case, use `display-table` to make this `<ul>` "bulletproof". :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate the contribution :). BTW how to chat one on one?

Answer (score 1):

*Along with your questions, I've taken your comments into consideration in preparing this answer.*

First, your HTML was invalid. The list was [nested improperly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) so I corrected that that in my answer.

**In answer to your first question...**

> how to position the prices at the baseline

... absolute positioning will work and will not prevent your price card from adjusting to different browsers, platforms or devices. It will be as responsive as the container it is in. Of course, you should test your code to make sure it works as intended.

Note that for `position: absolute` to work properly you must set the parent element to `position: relative`. This is because absolute positioning will move the element – in this case the `em` – *relative to its closest positioned ancestor* (which in this case should be the `li`). If the absolutely positioned element doesn't find a positioned ancestor, it will position the element relative to the `<body>`. So bottom line:

**To absolutely position a child element, set the parent element to `position: relative`.**

Here's an example using your code.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkohs6m5/1/)**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<!-- with corrections to improperly nested list -->
<div id="container">
    <h2>DRINK MENU</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><span>Latte</span><em>2.79</em></li>
        <li><span>Cappucino</span><em>2.99</em></li>
        <li><span>Cafe Americano more text more text more text more text</span>
        <em>1.80</em></li>
        <li><span>Espresso</span><em>2.00</em></li>
        <li><span>Carmel Macchiato more text more text more text more text</span>
        <em>10.00</em></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* based on your original code */

#container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 15px solid #886633;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
   padding: 5px;
}
h2 {
  width: 99%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
#container ul li {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed blue;
    position: relative;
}
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
em {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**In answer to your second question...**

> Just tell me why is relative position not working.

Actually, it's working fine. In the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) of things, it's positioned exactly where it belongs. Your descriptions are breaking to a new line because of the margin limitation you set in your `span`.

That being said, the `em` can still be positioned with `position: relative`. Change the value from 0. Your prices will (as defined by your style rule) move up or down as a group, depending on whether you use positive or negative numbers.

Your CSS rule:

```
em {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;

/* test these individually:
bottom: 25px;
bottom: -25px;
right: 25px;
right: -25px */
}
```

For more about positioning see the [`position` article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: I see your are correct about absolute position, it worked nicely. I still don't understand why relative position didn't work. I guess my theory is not clear about relative. 
P.S. i already gave tick to another answer, so it will be rude to remove it.

Comment: Not asking you to remove it. But I appreciate the thought. Read the article I included about the `position` property. Also read about Normal Flow. With that knowledge, some experience, and lots of testing, it will become clear. Btw, I use Chrome Dev Tools for testing variations, which is often very helpful.

Comment: This is off topic but how can i chat one on one to you or somebody else. I just earned the chat badge :)

Comment: About this question / answer?

Comment: how to use chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: yeah about this question answer

Comment: @VarunJ, you're not responding in the chat room. Let me know, otherwise I need to move on.

Comment: sorry went to sleep yesterday..can we do it again

Comment: how to access the chat room