# html FAQ ordered list

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm creating a website that has a FAQ page, and i was wondering if i could make an "ordered" list but instead of displaying

1. question ....
   a) answer .....
2. question
   a) answer
   etc.
   which would be done using:

```html
<ol>
  <li>question</li>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>answer</li>
      </ol>
  <li>question 2</li>
      <ol type="A">
        <li>answer 2</li>
        <ol>
</ol>
```

But is there a way to turn the numbers (and letters) into Question and Answer? or do i have to manually have to type Question and Answer for each line?
I have used JavaScript (and css) before but never Jquery. I would prefer to do it with JavaScript.

***EDIT:***
I was unaware of dd and dt *(description list)* when I asked this question. Originally i was trying to make one line say Question and then Answer on the next line, but the answer @Timothy Jones said made more sense then making an ordered list.

Comment: you can make it with server side or client side programming language. but, you need a database to store your QAs instead of 'hardcoding' the QAs.

Comment: There isn't doing to be a "submit question" which i check and answer as it is only a simple class exercise.

Comment: Something along these lines?.. http://jsfiddle.net/wxocofu6/

Comment: No because you still have the numbers

Comment: I didn't get what you explained @Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), and the CSS `::before` selector:

```html
<style type="text/css">
   dt::before {
       content: "Question: ";
   } 
   dd::before {
       content: "Answer: ";
   }
</style>
<dl>
  <dt>How would this look?</dt>
      <dd>it would look alright</dd>
  <dt>Alright, well how would this look?</dt>
      <dd>it would also look alright</dd>
</dl>
```

(add styles as appropriate). I prefer this over a javascript solution, as it doesn't require any processing after the page has loaded.

Comment: Perfect, that is what i was attempting to get!

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ol class="faq">
    <li>
        <ol><li></li></ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol><li></li></ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol><li></li></ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ol><li></li></ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol { list-style-type: none; }

ol.faq  { padding-left: 0; }

ol.faq > li::before {
    content: "Question";
    color: red;
}

ol.faq > li > ol > li::before {
    content: "Answer";
    color: green;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wxocofu6/5/

*Note that in your code your lists are improperly nested.*

Comment: About your note, this is how i was taught and it allows me to understand it easier. I'm trying to get into better habits, but how should it have been done?

Comment: If you're nesting a list within a list item, you don't close the list item until after the code for the nested items. In other words, consider `<li>` and `</li>` a container. All lists you want nested in this list item going between those tags. For a clear illustration see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set the icon style to none, and then using before in CSS, set the text.

```css
.questions li { list-style-type: none; font-weight: bold; color: black; } 
.questions li:before { content: "Question"; padding-right: 5px; color: red; }
.answer li { list-style-type: none; font-weight: bold; color: black; } 
.answer li:before { content: "Answer"; padding-right: 5px; color: red; }
```

```html
<ol class="questions">
  <li>Do you do the thing?</li>
      <ol class="answer">
        <li>Yes, we do.</li>
      </ol>
  <li>How do you do the thing?</li>
      <ol class="answer">
        <li>With lots of magic!</li>
        <ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is what i was original trying to do, but Timothy Jones bet you by a couple seconds, and his answer looks easier.

Comment: guess I should of left it un-styled! drat! Ah well, his is definitely a little simpler and cleaner.