# About Nested lists starting with the <li> tag

Tags: html

So after all the searching I've done for answers i came across
http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists and it has an example that tells me its nessasry but..

It does not explain the reasons that you would NEED or Want to do this in your list.

If you take a look at the <--- arrows I've created it points out what I'm confused about.

The list way at the bottom is the way that i USED to think it was done.

The list below is the example i need someone to explain.

BTW why is it when i put both of these in JSFiddle that they come up the same??

```
<ol>
  <li>Chapter One  <----------
    <ol>
      <li>Section One</li>
      <li>Section Two </li>
      <li>Section Three </li>
    </ol>
  </li>  <----------------
  <li>Chapter Two</li>
  <li>Chapter Three  </li>
</ol>
```

---

```html
<ol>
  <li>Chapter One</li>
  <ol>
    <li>Section One</li>
    <li>Section Two</li>
    <li>Section Three</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Chapter Two</li>
  <li>Chapter Three</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You've now asked the same question three times. If the answers you get an not satisfactory, then comment on them asking for clarification. Don't just repeat yourself and make other people duplicate effort.

Answer (score 3):

The top option is correct HTML. The other is not. The `ol` and `ul` tags should only have `li` children. (a list should only have list items as children which in turn have the content).

The fact that both work is probably leniency on the part of the browsers rather than the fact that they are both correct. (See the link that you sent for reference, particularly the section on [nesting lists](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists)). Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) on SO for more information on a similar question.