# HTML Nested List

Tags: html, list, nested

Hello I am trying to do a nested list in html and I can't figure out why my in3 is not showing up under my out3 (like inner 1 and 2).
I feel like this is one of those problems where I have to move a couple of letters around but ive been trying to fix this for an hour and cant seem to figure it out.

Heres the code that I have:

```
<ul> 
 <li>Out1
 <li>Out2</li> 
  <ul>
   <li>In1
   <li>In2</li>
    <ul>
     <li>De1</li>
     <li>De2</li>
    </ul> 
   </li>          
  </ul> 
 </li>
<li>Out3</li>
<u1>
 <li>In3</li>
</u1>
</u1>
```

Comment: Looks like you have a "1" rather than a "l"

Comment: You have a few `u1`s which should be `ul`s and `<ul><li>In3</li></ul>` would be invalid anyway, because you can basically only have `<li>`s as direct childs of `<ul>`s.

Comment: one of those "couple of hours after the work day has ended" kinda problems.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like **your problem is improper nesting**. If you want to put a list in a list, it needs to be nested within a nested list item (i.e. `ul > li > ul`), you should not have an unorder list directly in the root of another unordered list (i.e. `ul > ul`). This is also true for ordered lists (`ol`), and the mixture of ordered and unordered lists (e.g. `ol>ul`, `ul>ol`, `ol>ul>ul>ol>ul`, etc.) For more information on nesting, see the Stack Overflow question “[Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899337/1070047)”.

Your code should look more like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Out1</li>
    <li>Out2
        <ul>
            <li>In1</li>
            <li>In2
                <ul>
                    <li>De1</li>
                    <li>De2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Out3
        <ul>
            <li>In3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Additionally, your code displayed fine in my browser (`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36`), but it was malformed.

Answer (score 1):

it's because half-way through you switch to `<u1>`, instead if the correct `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `<ul>` should be inside the parent `<li>`