# Do I need to specify the key prop in this case and how would I do that then?

Tags: reactjs

The following code seems to work as expected: ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6crgvv5c/3/))

```
const headers = [
    {
        id: 'section-1',
        header: 'section 1',
    },
    {
        id: 'section-2',
        header: 'section 2',
    },
    {
        id: 'section-3',
        header: 'section 3',
        children: [
            {
                id: 'section-31',
                header: 'section 31',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 'section-311',
                        header: 'section 311',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'section-312',
                        header: 'section 312',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                id: 'section-32',
                header: 'section 32',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'section-4',
        header: 'section 4',
    },
];

const Nav = ({ headers, className }) =>
    <ul className={className}>
        {headers.map((header) => [
            <li className="list-group-item">
                {header.header}
            </li>,
            (header.children && header.children.length) ? (
                <Nav className="list-group" headers={header.children} />
            ) : null,
        ])}
    </ul>

const Toc = () =>
    <div id="my-super-interesting-nav">
        <Nav className="list-group nav-root" headers={headers} />
    </div>
```

I the future the `headers` array will be dynamic. I have three questions:

Why doesn't React complain that I haven't set the `key` prop on the child of the `headers.map()` call in `Nav`?

How bad will this confuse the reconciliation algorithm, given that the second assumption in the [React reconciliation algorithm](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) no longer holds?

If I wanted to specify a key in this case, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping function you use returns an array of elements, and not a react element, so key property is not expected thus no warning are being given.

I would advise you to refactor your code for mapping function to return react element like so:

```
{headers.map((header) =>
    <li className="list-group-item" key={header.id}>
        {header.header}
        {
            (header.children && header.children.length) 
            ? <Nav className="list-group" headers={header.children} /> 
            : null
        }
    </li>
)}
```

Note, that now we are able to use the `key` property and it's benefits.

https://jsfiddle.net/opm3Lsg8/2/

Comment: I used to think the key prop was needed to avoid "bugs" when the data changed, but it's starting to dawn on me that maybe it's just less efficient to not use them? Anyway, I can't refactor the markup the way you want me to because it would break my CSS.

Comment: yes, following the documentation keys are generally needed to provide optimization during re-rendering, also you can read [this explanation on toptal](https://www.toptal.com/react/interview-questions#iquestion-91681) (click "view the answer") to better understand the topic

Comment: ok, but note, that this approach (putting nested list inside li-element, instead of alongside) is more preferable, [more info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5899394/7049654)

Comment: Ah, yes you're probably right. I read the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) on `<ul>` but I think the section on permitted content there needs to be updated. But the main reason I'm putting them alongside is because <del>that's how [bootstrap list groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group) works</del> because I saw some example on how to nest bootstrap list groups that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mapping an object in ReactJS, you will always have to add a key to it.

From the moment a loop or any other form of iteration is used this is required.

Just adding a key with the same value as id will fix it:

```
key={id}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

```
headers.map((header, index) => {
   <div key={index}>
      header
   </div>
}
```

Comment: But React isn't printing any warnings in the console? And how do I add the key prop when the map function returns an array of elements and not just one element?

Comment: if it returns an array you can also get the key/index from them.
I added it to my answer