# How to target the inner ul's first li?

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm looking for some CSS to increasing the padding between the li and the li li. As you can see in the image, indented list is too close to the bottom of li. What css can I write to stop this from happening in my current wordpress theme? Thanks.

[li issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiMWt.png)

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will target the second unordered list's first list item.

The `>` is a child combinator and it pretty much means target the unordered list directly one level deeper. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators.

And well `ul li` (so just using a space) means select all list item of that unordered list.

And then `ul li:first-child` means only target the first list item of that unordered list.

```css
ul > li > ul li:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li> Item </li>
      <li> Item </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Item </li>
</ul>
```

Edited to incorporate Matthias' suggestion.

Comment: The [proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) to create nested lists is to have the inner `<ul>` as a child of the outer `<li>`. Then, the rule becomes: `ul > li > ul li:first-child { margin-top: 20px}`

Comment: @MatthiasBraun Nice! Just added the change.