# How do I make tabs inside tabs in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please tell me how to make tabs inside tabs in this code?

```js
$('.tabs-box').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.tabs-sel span:first').addClass('current');
    $(this).find('.tabs-b:first').addClass('visible');
});
$('.tabs-sel').delegate('span:not(.current)', 'click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current')
    .parents('.tabs-box').find('.tabs-b').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(400);
});
```

```css
.tabs-b {display:none;}
.tabs-b.visible {display:block;}
.tabs-sel {padding:20px 0 0 20px;}
.tabs-sel span {display:inline-block; padding:10px 20px; vertical-align:top; cursor:pointer;}
.tabs-sel span.current {background-color:#4e647a;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-box">
    <div class="tabs-sel"><span class="current">1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span></div>
    <div class="tabs-b visible">12</div>
    <div class="tabs-b">13</div>
    <div class="tabs-b">14</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/senopsisder/pen/zaEpBV

Comment: What do you mean by "tabs". Divs with a class?

Comment: https://codepen.io/senopsisder/pen/zaEpBV

Comment: You've already shared that link in your question. No need to post it again.

Comment: Consider ul and li
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: It is necessary to make, approximately as on a picture, only with my code. Tabs, and in each tab is another tab https://c.radikal.ru/c31/1806/28/050ad2713774.png

Comment: Consider ul and li stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/ It's not that

Comment: Please show any attempts you've made at fixing your own problem, and any research you've done.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Try something like this in one of the sub tabs:

```
  <div class="tabs-b visible">
    <div class="tabs-sel">
    <span class="current">12</span>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Answers are better when they explain the alternate code presented. It's also a good idea to ensure your suggestions work before posting. In this case, you can click the "Copy snippet to answer", modify it with your suggested code, and click the Run button to ensure it works.

Comment: Thanks but It's not that

Comment: Whatever happened to static analysis?