# styling a nested list in CSS

Tags: css, html-lists

According to this well-rated SO post [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337) the best-practice way to make a nested list is this:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two with subitems:
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Final list item</li> </ul>
```

however I'm having real problems styling a list made in this way. I want each item in the list to have a specific height but I can't use `li { height: 40px; }` because the height of the second li also includes all the inner list. See here for an example http://jsfiddle.net/rujg3zyk.

The problem comes down to the fact that the second outer `li` element contains both some plain text and a block display element. This seems like a 'code smell' to me.

what's the best way of formatting this list so that each line is 40px high?

Comment: Just use a min-height instead? http://jsfiddle.net/rujg3zyk/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply line-height instead of height

```
ul li {
  background-color:yellow;
  line-height:40px;
}

ul li li {
 background-color:red;
 line-height:40px;
}
```

height:40px will apply 40px for all the listed items, so that two clild 'li' wont fit inside the 40px of the parent 'li'

Answer (score 1):

The way you have given here, is not a valid syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two with subitems:</li>
    <!-- Problem here... -->
    <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

You cannot nest `<ul>` directly under `<ul>` in this case. You need to do is:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two with subitems:
    <ul>
        <li>Subitem 1</li>
        <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

And the above code is perfectly valid. You don't need to use a `height` but try using `min-height`. I strongly advice you against using `height` (as that has to be calculated by the contents).

Comment: sorry, as soon as I posted it, I realised I had copied the incorrect sample :(

Answer (score 0):

**Your code** 
Your code :

```
<ul>
    <li>List item one</li>
    <li>List item two with subitems:
        <ul>
            <li>Subitem 1</li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Final list item</li> 
</ul>
```

is correct you need some changes read below:

The nested list should be **inside a `<li>` element** of the list in which it is nested.

Link to the W3C Wiki on Lists (taken from comment below): [HTML Lists Wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists).

Link to the HTML5 W3C `ul` spec: [HTML5 `ul`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element). Note that a `ul` element may contain exactly zero or more `li` elements.  The same applies to [HTML5 `ol`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element).
The description list ([HTML5 `dl`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element)) is similar, but allows both `dt` and `dd` elements.

More Notes:

- `dl` = definition list.
- `ol` = ordered list (numbers).
- `ul` = unordered list (bullets).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you could use `min-height` instead of `height`:

```css
ul li {
  background-color:yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
}

ul li li {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item one</li>
  <li>List item two with subitems:
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
      <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

Of course, it could expand to higher heights if there is more content, so that is why I am not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is closer but still not quite what I wanted because the text "List item two with subitems" is not in its own 40px high "box". the line-height solution seems to give exactly what I was looking form.