# Submenu on Menu hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem, I would like to put a second submenu, but in a way that I don't know I can't do it, either the second submenu is displayed at the bottom of the first, or some either the menu on which you are it displays the first submenu.
Please help me to be able to have several menus with several submenu
Html

```
<header id="header">
  <h1>Voyager Menu</h1>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="hover">Item1</li>
    <li id="hover2">Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sous-menu">
    <ul id="inv-hover">
      <li>Subitem1</li>
      <li>Subitem1</li>
      <li>Subitem1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sous-menu">
    <ul id="inv-hover2">
      <li>Subitem1-1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

But when i hover the second menu item `Item1`, it only shows me the `Subitem1,Subitem2, Subitem3` but not the `Subitem1-1`.
This is the Script

```js
var head = document.getElementById("header");
var hover = document.getElementById("hover");
var hover2 = document.getElementById("hover2");
var invHover = document.getElementById("inv-hover");
var invHover2 = document.getElementById("inv-hover2");

hover.addEventListener("mouseover", expand);
hover2.addEventListener("mouseover", expand);
invHover.addEventListener("mouseover", expand);
invHover2.addEventListener("mouseover", expand);
head.addEventListener("mouseout", close);

function expand() {
  // hover.style.background = "#03a9f4";
  // hover.style.color = "#fff";
  head.className = "expand";
}

function close() {
  // hover.style.background = "#f4f4f4";
  // hover.style.color = "#000";
    head.className = "";
}
```

```css
#header { 
  text-align:center;
  background:#fff;
  padding-top:25px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

#header.expand {
  height: 128px;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

ul.menu {
  margin-top:10px;
}

ul.menu li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
  background:#fff;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

ul.menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
}
.sous-menu {
  text-align:center;
  color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
ul#inv-hover {
  background:#fff;
  height:100%;
}

ul#inv-hover li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  line-height:40px;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px 0;
}

section h1 {
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Voyager Menu</h1>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li id="hover">Item1</li>
    <li id="hover2">Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sous-menu">
    <ul id="inv-hover">
      <li>Subitem1</li>
      <li>Subitem1</li>
      <li>Subitem1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sous-menu">
    <ul id="inv-hover2">
      <li>Subitem1-1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

I want to open a the `SubItems 1-1`, when i hover on `Item2`
Thank you for you help.

Comment: I think that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list) will help as well :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp) example will help you with adding sub-menus and styling it.