# Traversing nested HTML lists recursively

Tags: java, html, recursion, jsoup, nested-lists

I am unable to take the HTML below and put it into a list like:

```java
List<String> output = Arrays.asList(
    new String[] {
        "First Level-Second Level--Third Level",
        "a-b--c1",
        "a-b--c2",
        "a-b--c3",
        "a-b2--c1",
        "a-b2--c2",
        "a-b2--c3"
    });
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First Level</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Third Level</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <ul>
        <li>b</li>
        <ul>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
        <li>b2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>c1</li>
            <li>c2</li>
            <li>c3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I have loaded it into Jsoup to go through them like elements. The code I have is below:

```java
public static String recHTML(Element element, String str) { 
    str += "-" + element.ownText(); 
    if (element.children().size() == 0) return str + "--" + element.ownText(); 
    else { 
        for (int i = 0; i < element.children().size(); i++) { 
            Element next = element.child(i); 
            str += recHTML(next, str); 
        }
    }
}
```

I am returning the string with the dashes to use regex to split them into an array to have different levels of indentation. I am struggling to get my output to match up and no matter what I try I just can't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Your `recHTML` does not compile. Are you missing a return statement?

Comment: Do you consider something like this a valid HTML input for your method: `<ul><ul><li>a</li></ul><li>b</li></ul>`?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Comment: But that's not considered valid HTML and neither is your example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list

Comment: I think your task will simplify dramatically once you edit your HTML to something that's valid with the help of a validator (for example, [this one](https://validator.w3.org/)).

Comment: I might be at a loss because i do not create that HTML it retrieved through an API from ado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you create a program stub like bellow:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class App {
    private static List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Element input = Jsoup.parse(/*your HTML list*/).selectFirst("body").child(0);
        recHTML(input, "", "");
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void recHTML(Element element, String chain, String link) {
        // Todo! 
    }
}
```

Now let's consider your invalid HTML example and its valid equivalent

### Invalid HTML input list

```html
<ul>
    <li>First Level</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Second Level</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Third Level</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <ul>
        <li>b</li>
        <ul>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
        <li>b2</li>
        <ul>
            <li>c1</li>
            <li>c2</li>
            <li>c3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Currently, you're trying to implement something like a *depth-first search (DFS)*. A typical DFS won't do. Why? Because the HTML structure you provided has multiple leaf nodes that do not terminate a *chain*.

Suppose we call each element of your `output` a *chain*. As you traverse the HTML tree in a DFS manner, note that a *chain* is complete
as soon as you find a `li` element without `ul` siblings. This should be your *end condition*. As for the recursion step, think about how to handle `ul` and `li` elements. It is not easy to define; currently, my solution only works for your specific input.

Your `recHTML` implementation for this is bound to be ugly since there's no direct nested *chain* from the root to leaf nodes. New edge cases will continuously come up where your code will not work and you'll keep making edits.

```java
public static void recHTML(Element element, String chain, String link) {
    if (element.parent().children().select("ul").isEmpty()) {
        output.add(chain);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < element.children().size(); i++) {
        Element next = element.child(i);
        if (next.tagName().equals("ul")) {
            recHTML(next, chain  + link + element.child(i - 1).ownText(), link + '-');
        } else {
            recHTML(next, chain  + link + next.ownText(), link);
        }
    }
}
```

### Valid HTML input list

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    First level
    <ul>
      <li>
        Second Level
        <ul>
          <li>Third Level</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    a
    <ul>
      <li>
        b
        <ul>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        b2
        <ul>
          <li>c1</li>
          <li>c2</li>
          <li>c3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As suggested in my comments, your problem lies in the input. Suppose we somehow *transform* your input HTML to the above markup. Then the solution becomes a lot cleaner and more straightforward - a simple DFS will work!

```java
public static void recHTML(Element element, String chain, String link) { 
    if (element.children().isEmpty()) {
        output.add(chain);
    }

    for (Element child : element.children()) {
        if (child.tagName().equals("li")) {
            recHTML(child, chain + link + child.ownText(), link + "-");
        } else {
            recHTML(child, chain, link);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Fun fact: Java HTML tidy tool [JTidy](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jtidy/jtidy) has corrected your HTML input in a slightly different way than I have:

```html
<!-- original snippet -->
<li>First Level</li>
<ul>
  <li>Second Level</li>
  <!-- omitted elements for brevity -->
</ul>

<!-- snippet, corrected by jtidy -->
<li>First Level</li>
<li style="list-style: none">
  <ul>
    <li>Second Level</li>
    <!-- omitted elements for brevity -->
  </ul>
</li>
```

Personally, I don't think it corrects it the right way - [Proper way to make HTML nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899337/proper-way-to-make-html-nested-list)